# msmtp does not set sender address, when I use it with php mail()

Tags: php, msmtp

in php.ini, I set :
sendmail_path = "/usr/local/bin/msmtp -f info@abisy.de -C /var/www/vhosts/abisy.de/.msmtprc -t"

but the EMails sent with php mail() are landing in the spam dir of my mail account.
These mails do not contain a sender address

I use the -f option, and additionally I set the From: header in php

Answer (score 0):

The `-f` option sets the SMTP envelope sender. In order to appease your spam filter, you'll need to set a `From:` header. These usually contain the same value. You can set the `From:` header by passing the `$additional_headers` parameter to the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. Note, doing this won't guarantee that your emails will stay out of the spam folder. You may have to take additional measures like implementing [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and/or [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail). Overall, dealing with emails is usually much easier if you just use an API service like [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/).